# foreach loop is slower than for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing, time-series

I have a huge number of times series to model, each time series takes about ~2 min.

I have a lot of csv with several time series inside.

```
numCores <- detectCores()
numCores
registerDoParallel(numCores)
foreach (i=1:numfiles, .packages = c("tidyverse", "forecast", "TSA", "tseries", "caschrono") ) %dopar% {
  df <- read_delim(myfiles[i], delim = ";")
  for (key in (df[["KEY"]] %>% unique())){
    df_b <- df[df["KEY"] == key,]
    [...]
    if (...) {
      [...]
      serie <- ts(train, frequency = 365)
      model <- Arima(serie, order = c(0, 1, 3), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 0), period = 365))
      i <- i + 1
      name <- paste(modeldir, key, sep = "-")
      saveRDS(object = model, file = name)
      }
    else {
    }
    })
  }
}
```

I put some [...] because it's useless code that don't take any times.
I have 8 cores and it is much slower, I seek that it's normal with lots of things that take little time, each for loop takes like ~ 12 min because there is multiple time series on one csv.

I didnt find any others solutions that exists in R. To be more precise, by launching with the simple for loop on all the csv the calculation time normally exceeds 20 days.

Sorry for my bad english :)

Edit :

Thanks to both of you.
So I tried map() like this :

```
map(.x = myfiles, .f = treatment)
```

where treatment function is :

```
treatment <- function(path){
df <- read_delim(path, delim = ";")
  for (key in (df[["KEY"]] %>% unique())){
    df_b <- df[df["KEY"] == key,]
    [...]
    if (...) {
      [...]
      serie <- ts(train, frequency = 365)
      model <- Arima(serie, order = c(0, 1, 3), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 0), period = 365))
      i <- i + 1
      name <- paste(modeldir, key, sep = "-")
      saveRDS(object = model, file = name)
      }
    else {
    }
    })
  }
}
```

it functions and makes me models on my directory but it's not in parallel it's one after another... I used `registerDoParallel(numCores)`, how can i do that ?

For lapply/parLapply I did not manage to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: I used to use `foreach` but now I use the R package `purrr` and the `map()` function. Incredibly faster.

Comment: Thank you TheSciGuy I will try !

Comment: the parLapply family of functions is also quite useful for me